# Is it possible to include dynamic data in a polymer element preferences?

Tags: javascript, html, json, rest, polymer

I did it in this way for example in a table:

```
<dom-module id="rest-api">
<template>
    <style>
        :host {
            display: block;
            box-sizing: border-box; 
        }
    </style>
    <iron-ajax 
        auto
        url="http://localhost:8080/cockpit/clients"
        handle-as="json"
        last-response="{{response}}"
    ></iron-ajax>
        <table>
            <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{response}}">
                <tr>
                    <td>{{item.id}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.status}}</td>
                </tr>
            </template>
        </table>
        *<google-chart
            type='pie'
            options='{"title": "Client-Status"}'
            data='[["Status", "Quantity"], ["",0], ["Offline", **{{off}}**], ["",0], ["Online", **{{on}}**]]'
        ></google-chart>*
</template>
```

through my rest api i got an array of clients, but i don't know how to count them and how to bind the values in my pie chart.

Thanks for help!

Comment: I guess you need to add more information. How does the data look like you get from the server? I don't see how the code in your question is related to "an array of clients".

Comment: thats just the simple json data i got --> 

[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "status": "online"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "status": "offline"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "status": "online"
  }
]

Comment: Here is an example that may help: http://plnkr.co/edit/N5ljGrqk8QG2pBXJaHSB?p=preview

Comment: thanks, that will help!